# Two rulers passing each other

Tags: special-relativity

In our frame of reference there is a ruler moving from the left to the right with speed $v$ and a point mass moving from right to left with speed $v$.

Length contraction will cause use to observe the ruler with length $l^\prime=\frac{l}{\gamma}$, therefore the time it takes to have the point mass pass the ruler will be $\Delta t=\frac{l^\prime}{2v}=\frac{l}{2v\gamma}$.

**What would now happen if we would not have a point mass moving from the right to the left but another ruler also of rest length $l$?**

Comment: Think of the new ruler as two point masses that are (when at rest) 12 inches apart.

Comment: But wouldn't both lengths be contracted?

Comment: yes they would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the $\Delta t$ you describe in the problem statement, I'm assuming you're interested in the time over which the two rulers are intersecting in your frame.  The distance between the two ends of the second ruler in your frame is $l' = \frac{l}{\gamma}$ also.  Let's call the two ends $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is closer to the original ruler (ruler 1) initially.  $A$ takes $\Delta t = \frac{l}{2v\gamma}$ to pass through ruler 1, as you say. Right as $A$ finishes passing through ruler 1, $B$ is beginning to come into contact with ruler 1, since the two rulers have the same intrinsic length and are going the same speed in your frame.  $B$ also takes $\frac{l}{2v\gamma}$ to pass through ruler 1, so the total time the two rulers are intersecting is $\frac{l}{2v\gamma} + \frac{l}{2v\gamma} = \frac{l}{v\gamma}$.